# How to set date and time also timezone in php same as Parse.com

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm Facing issue with Date and Time when i migrate Parse.com to Php Server.
can any one please tell me which DateTime format Parse.com Use and Which TimeZone ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: DateTime functions are default set to the servers timezone. If you want this to be a specific timezone then use `date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )` with this being a list of supported timezones http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com is using DateTime Object to store the date and time with UTC timezone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$startTime = new DateTime('2016-09-19 10:30:00', new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
$startTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));


$parseObject->set('startTime', $startTime);
```